# implementation of datepicker with form helper

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

So I'm running bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem and want to implement this in to my form:

```
<div class="input-group date">
<input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>

$('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
  maxViewMode: 2,
  multidate: true,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: "1,2,3,4,5",
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

How this thing should look with form helper? 
My current code looks like this:

```
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
      <%= f.label :date %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :date %>  
    </div>
```

I assume jquery code will go to application.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as following:

```
<div class="col-md-2 ">
  <%= f.label :date %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :date, id: "id_datepicker" %>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#id_datepicker').datepicker({
      maxViewMode: 2,
      multidate: true,
      daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
      daysOfWeekHighlighted: "1,2,3,4,5",
      todayHighlight: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Following as official document of `jquery datepicker`, you must put code inside `jquery`.

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

Comment: @Karolis i updated my answer, you can check it again ?